# Is it possible to label (tag) a value of a (l3keys) key-value in order to reuse it elsewhere easily?

Tags: labels, key-value, l3keys, tags

I have a command (`\people[⟨options⟩]{⟨name⟩}`) for entering people. Its optional argument lets the user specify possible people's (possibly multiple) attribute(s) with a (`l3keys`) key–value system: `attribute={⟨value A⟩},attribute={⟨value B⟩},...` (these values are internally put to a sequence).

Now, some people may share the same attribute's `⟨value⟩`s with people already entered and, in such a case, these `⟨value⟩`s have to be treated differently. To this end, there is another key–value: `duplicateattribute={⟨value⟩}`.

I could manage with two parallel sequences ("attribute" and "duplicateattribute") as in the following MWE (involving `datatool`):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{datatool}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\DTLnewdb{_mymodule_people}

\seq_new:N \l_mymodule_people_attributes_seq
\seq_new:N \l_mymodule_people_duplicateattributes_seq

\keys_define:nn { mymodule/people } {%
  attribute .code:n = \seq_put_right:Nn \l_mymodule_people_attributes_seq {#1},
  duplicateattribute .code:n =\seq_put_right:Nn \l_mymodule_people_duplicateattributes_seq {#1}
}

\cs_new_protected:Nn \_mymodule_enter_people:n
 {
  \DTLnewrow{_mymodule_people}
  \DTLnewdbentry{_mymodule_people}{name}{#1}
  \DTLnewdbentry{_mymodule_people}{attribute}{\tl_to_str:n{#1}}
  \DTLnewdbentry{_mymodule_people}{duplicateattribute}{\tl_to_str:n{#1}}
 }

\NewDocumentCommand \people { O{} m }
{
  \seq_clear:N \l_mymodule_people_attributes_seq
  \seq_clear:N \l_mymodule_attributes_seq
  \seq_clear:N \l_mymodule_people_duplicateattributes_seq

  \keys_set:nn { mymodule/people } { #1 }

  \_mymodule_enter_people:n {#2}

  \seq_new:c { g_mymodule_attributes_ \tl_to_str:n{#2} _seq }
  \seq_gset_eq:cN { g_mymodule_attributes_ \tl_to_str:n{#2} _seq } \l_mymodule_people_attributes_seq

  \seq_new:c { g_mymodule_duplicateattributes_ \tl_to_str:n{#2} _seq }
  \seq_gset_eq:cN { g_mymodule_duplicateattributes_ \tl_to_str:n{#2} _seq }
  \l_mymodule_people_duplicateattributes_seq

%  \seq_show:c { g_mymodule_attributes_ \tl_to_str:n{#2} _seq }
%  \seq_show:c { g_mymodule_duplicateattributes_ \tl_to_str:n{#2} _seq }
}
\ExplSyntaxOff
\begin{document}
\people                                {People 0}
\people[attribute          = {value A}]{People 1}
\people[attribute          = {value B},
        attribute          = {value C}]{People 2}
\people[attribute          = {value D},
        duplicateattribute = {value B},
        attribute          = {value E}]{People 3}
\end{document}
```

But this has the drawback that the duplicate attribute's `⟨value⟩`s have to be duplicated (see `value B` in the example: in real life, the values may be much longer): that's boring and problematic from a maintenance point of view.

Hence, I'd like to be able to optionally label (tag) `⟨value⟩`s in order to reuse them elsewhere just by duplicating their label and not themselves as a whole, e.g. in the following way:

```
[...]
\people[attribute          = [tagB]{value B},
        attribute          = {value C}]{People 2}
\people[attribute          = {value D},
        duplicateattribute = {tagB},
        attribute          = {value E}]{People 3}
[...]
```

where:

- `value B` is tagged with `tagB` (`[tagB]{value B})` and reused elsewhere (`duplicateattribute = {tagB})`
- the other values are not tagged because not reused elsewhere.

Is it possible?

Comment: Wouldn't it be simpler to declare duplicate attributes outside a `\people` command? By the way, what you do with `datatool` seems an application for a property list.

Comment: @egreg Only the duplicate ones? And it is necessary to specify who share what attributes' values, e.g. the people whose attributes have also the `value B` value. About `datatool`, I suspect for a long time now that the intersection between this package's and `expl3` property lists' features is not empty, but could you be more explicit?

Comment: I was thinking to something like `\defineduplicateattribute{tag}{text}`, so in a `\people` command you can say `\people[attribute=foo,duplicateattribute=tag]{X Y}`. Having all tags in a fixed place, say just before `\begin{document}` may help maintenance.

Comment: @egreg That is in direct conflict with my taste of symmetry: ordinary attributes treated differently from duplicate ones :) In fact, my problem is a many-to-many one (many people to many attributes) and I first considered defining people in one hand, attributes in the other hand and, finally, the many-to-many pairs. But this has the drawback all the people and all the attributes have to be tagged, even if unnecessary: if a people has non shared attributes, neither him/her nor his/her attributes should have to be tagged ideally. In conclusion, I guess I would follow your advice :)