# How to properly parse [...]{...} with expl3?

Tags: parsing, l3keys

What would be the more efficient way of parsing `[...]{...}` with `expl3`, that is to get the content inside the brackets in one variable and the content inside the braces in another one?

This question is in fact related to [Is it possible to label (tag) a value of a (l3keys) key-value in order to reuse it elsewhere easily?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/280346/18401), and what I have in mind is to get `tagB` and `value B` of a value passed to a (`l3keys`) key–value system, such as:

```
\people[attribute          = [tagB]{value B},
        attribute          = {value C}]{People 2}
```

I guess this would involve `l3quark` quarks but I'm not sure.

Comment: Define a command with signature `{om}` and use it inside l3keys.

Comment: I was about to say the same as Manuel, although this seems quite abusing the system.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As egreg says, this might be abusing the system, but it's definitely useful. I don't know what's the most correct solution for this (and having xparse to parse optional arguments calls to be used, altough it's mixing a little bit the things).

```
\quark_new:N \q_denis
\NewDocumentCommand \denis_people_attribute:ww { o u\q_denis }
 { ⟨Whatever definition you want, using #1 and #2 and \IfValueTF{#1}, etc.⟩ }
\keys_define:nn { denis / people }
 {
  attribute .code:n = \denis_people_attribute:ww #1 \q_denis ,
 }
\keys_set:nn { denis / people }
 {
  attribute = [tagB]{valueB} ,
  attribute = {value C}
 }
```

In any case, I don't know how to call the command `\peoplesattribute` seems “weird” there, but mixing `\denis_people_attribute:w` with `\NewDocumentCommand` seems also weird. May be an inner xparse function should be given? E.g., `\xparse_new_command:Nnn \foo:w { o m } { .. #1 #2 .. }`. I really don't know.

Comment: Inserting your code between `\ExplSyntaxOn` and `\ExplSyntaxOff` in the preamble of `.tex` file (that just uses `xparse` package and has `Foo` content) leads to the error: `Runaway argument?
{valueB}\tl_set:Nn \l__keys_module_tl {denis/people}\__keyval_key_value_elt_1:n
n \ETC.
! Paragraph ended before \peoplesattribute  was complete.`. Maybe I did something wrong. Furthermore, I would prefer not use a public command for my ugly internal machination :)

Comment: But `\keys_set:nn` should be in the document (only in my example, because it *prints* text), not in the preamble (or inside your defined `\people` command). In any case, updated a little bit, the problem was using kernel quarks like `\q_nil`, I defined `\q_denis` and used it.

Comment: That works now but, if I'm right, `\detokenize{[#1]}` and `\detokenize{{#2}}` should be replaced by `\detokenize{#1}` and `\detokenize{#2}` respectively.

Comment: No, it was just a dummy definition so you see that it works and recognizes the optional argument. You should change that definition so it does what you want.

Comment: Okay but in order to get `tagB` and `value B` in case of `attribute= [tagB]{value B}` (as asked in the OP), `\detokenize{[#1]}` and `\detokenize{{#2}}` should be replaced by `\detokenize{#1}` and `\detokenize{#2}` respectively. Otherwise, what is obtained is `[tagB]` and `–valueB ̋`.

Comment: @DenisBitouzé No. Forget that. That's a definition I made for the sole purpose of clarifying and testing that it works. `#1` is `tagB` (or nothing, you check with xparse's `\IfValueTF`) and `#2` is `value B`. You do with `#1` and `#2` whatever you want. Forget about `\detokenize`. (And, by the way, if it prints like that, it has to do with `fontencoding`.)